# Entity Framewok 5 - working out if the database is sql server or sql CE (compact edition)

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a function to allow an administrator to create and download database backup files (included below, but not necessary to read or follow in order to answer the question). Is there a way to tell if the database backing the entity framework context is ce - if so I will implement a different backup strategy (ie just copy the .sdf file using the filesystem - although I will have to figure out a way to check if there are any open connections first).

thank you.

---

```
private const string dbBakDirectory = "~/App_Data/DbBackups/";
public const string versionFormat = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd HHmm}";
private const string namingFormat = "DAB Trial Database " + versionFormat;
private const string FullName = " FULL";
private const string DifferentialName = " (dif)";

public static int BackupDataBase(Database db, string dbName, string outputPath, bool differential=false)
{
    if (!outputPath.EndsWith(".bak")) { outputPath += ".bak"; }
    int sqlReturn = db.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        "BACKUP DATABASE [" + dbName + "] TO  DISK = N'" + outputPath + "' WITH " + (differential ? "DIFFERENTIAL," : "") + " CHECKSUM");
    if (sqlReturn != -1) { return sqlReturn; }
    return db.ExecuteSqlCommand("RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM  DISK = N'" + outputPath + "'");
}

public string CreateDbBackup(bool differential = false)
{
    string outputFileName = Path.Combine(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(dbBakDirectory), string.Format(namingFormat, DateTime.Now) + (differential ? DifferentialName : FullName));
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder conStr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    using (DbContext context = new DataContext())
    {
        conStr.ConnectionString = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
        BackupDataBase(context.Database, conStr.InitialCatalog, outputFileName, differential);
    }
    return outputFileName;
}
```

#### Edit

Thanks to qujck I am now using

```
using (DbContext context = new DataContext())
{
    conStr.ConnectionString = context.Database.Connection.ConnectionString;
    string version = SqlVersion(context.Database).ToLower();
    if (version.Contains("compact"))
    {
        string inputFileName = conStr.DataSource.Replace("|DataDirectory|", HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/App_Data/"));
        System.IO.File.Copy(inputFileName, outputFileName + ".sdf");
    }
    else
    {
        BackupDataBase(context.Database, conStr.InitialCatalog, outputFileName, differential);
    }
}

public static string SqlVersion(Database db)
{
    try
    {
        return db.SqlQuery(typeof(string), "SELECT @@version").Cast<string>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException e)
    {
        return "Sql Server Compact Edition (version unspecified)"; 
        // could also just return the data provider, return e.Source; ('Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is surprisingly complicated!

The simplest method (a.k.a. hack) is to execute `SELECT @@version` using `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery` (or `DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand`) and if it fails assume you are running CE.

Comment: Thank you - it is a hack, but on the neater end of the spectrum of hacks - see edit above as to how I implemented your well thought suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Normal program flow based on exceptions is not a good pattern, I propose this simple solution:

```
return context.Database.Connection is SqlCeConnection;
```